# How to block container communication (172.17.0.0/16) except of the default gateway with iptables

Tags: iptables, docker, containers

I am using docker to run containers.
I don't want the containers to have access to the other containers but I want them to still have access to external communication like using `apt update`.

The containers network is `172.17.0.0/16`, if I just block like that:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i docker0 -d 172.17.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

It works but then they can't use `apt update`, it can't find from where to download because it probably goes out from the gateway.
Therefore I wanted to allow connection to the gateway (`172.17.0.1`) so I tried to allow it like that:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i docker0 -d 172.17.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o docker0 -d 172.17.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
```

But the problem still exist, it can't use `apt update`:

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

Only when I remove the block rule it works again:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i docker0 -d 172.17.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Running two debian containers with 172.17.0.2 and 172.17.0.3 on docker0, they can't communicate with your FORWARD DROP rule (that's because Docker activates `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` by the way), but they don't have any issue to reach the host through 172.17.0.1 , including DNS requests, or successfully running `apt update` and `apt install hello`.

Comment: Maybe you have other blocking rules and you just need as you did with FORWARD, to replace these `-A` by `-I`.

Comment: Or your DNS is handled by a container... or a proxy... you'll have to do separate tests with IP and DNS to figure out what's wrong

Comment: And last but not least comment: you're supposed to create additional networks and run containers in them for isolation rather than having to fiddle yourself (instead of Docker) with rules. https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to stop communications between containers:

Create a network with ICC disabled:

```
docker network create -o com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc=false my_secure_bridge
```

Test with creating two containers:

```
docker run --name cnt1 --network=my_secure_bridge -it --rm -d alpine
docker run --name cnt2 --network=my_secure_bridge -it --rm -d alpine
```

```
docker inspect cnt1 | grep -i 172
    "Gateway":   "172.19.0.1",
    "IPAddress": "172.19.0.2",
```

```
docker inspect cnt2 | grep -i 172
    "Gateway":   "172.19.0.1",
    "IPAddress": "172.19.0.3",
```

exec into one and check:

```
docker exec -it cnt1 sh
```

check connectivity to outer world:

```
/ # ping -c 3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=114 time=0.852 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=114 time=0.990 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=2 ttl=114 time=0.808 ms
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.808/0.883/0.990 ms
```

check connectivity to another container:

```
/ # ping -w 5 172.19.0.3
PING 172.19.0.3 (172.19.0.3): 56 data bytes
--- 172.19.0.3 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

Comment: but what will the security benefit, in case of the container cant connect each other?

Comment: @djdomi, the benefit is that this will solve the problem in the description, where the topic starter stated, that they "want the containers to have access to the other containers but I want them to still have access to external communication".

Comment: write typo accident? you say to all have to access anywhere, that's a default behavior if correctly configured?